# Stack with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So i am trying to create a screen,i made half way through but whenever i try to add textfield with in row ,i made to do half way with overlapping images  but when  i try to run it it throws error like this,it happen when i try to add textfield

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.
This happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite width constraint. For example, if the InputDecorator is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the TextField that contains it.
'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart':
Failed assertion: line 926 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity'
```

**Code for Design**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Registration", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/gym.png',
                  height: 150, width: double.infinity, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90, left: 20),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/user_avatar.png"),
                radius: 55.0,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'USer'),
                ),

                TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: 'Mo'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because TextField requires Width of whole screen, to avoid it you can wrap it inside Expanded widget.

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/crown.png',
                  height: 150,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'USer'),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Mo'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90, left: 20),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/crown.png"),
            radius: 55.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: how can put this under the circle image @Viren V Varasadiya

Comment: which circle image ? image with photo icon ?

Comment: i would like to suggest use column widget instead of using stack widget.

Comment: i added some more code to demonstrate how you can achieve very easily. now change positions accordingly .

Comment: Can you help me with that,i tried it before coming with code,after long search this what i did,you don't need to entire thing,can you atleast upto the first row textfield,Please... @Viren V Varasadiya

Comment: No,it's not working,the textfield  is shows under the image with photo icon & also,those text fields are showing in single line even though it's seperate line,Can you help me how to do this with Colum widget  instead of  stack widget,Please .....@Viren V Varasadiya

Comment: I updated please check again and change sizedbox height which works for you.

Comment: Now it Works,But those text fields are showing in single line,i tried to add  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, But it's same,i am not sure why is that @Viren V Varasadiya

Comment: You have to copy whole row widget and paste it below row.

Comment: Ok i got it,just added Padding to Textfield,it's good @Viren V Varasadiya

Comment: Accept my answer if helps you.@abhijith